# form validation - function with patterMismatch does not display the error

Tags: javascript, forms

I am wondering if anyone can point out why the function with `validity.patternMismatch` does not display the appropriate error messagge, while the same function with `validity.valueMissing`displays it.

Thank you.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hvutpw4a/4/)

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs.forEach(function(input) {

  const e_space = input.closest("div div").querySelector(".error");

  input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
    if (input.classList.contains("input-red")) {
      input.classList.remove("input-red")
    }
  })
  input.addEventListener("blur", function() {

    //pattern mismatch -still need to seperate them to text/number/email
    if (input.validity.patternMismatch) {
      if (e_space) {
        e_space.textContent = "This field can only contain letters from a-z.";
        input.classList.add("b-r");
      }
      input.classList.add("input-red");
    } else {
      e_space.textContent = "";
      input.classList.remove("b-r");
    }


    //if empty
    input.value = input.value.trim();
    if (input.validity.valueMissing) {
      if (e_space) {
        e_space.textContent = "This field must not be empty.";
        input.classList.add("b-r");
      }
      input.classList.add("input-red");
    } else {
      e_space.textContent = "";
      input.classList.remove("b-r");
    }

  })
})
```

```html
<label for="surname">Surname:<span class="asterx">*</span></label>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" required placeholder="Please enter your Surname" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,15}" />
  <div class="error" id="e_surname"></div>
</div>
<label for="tel">Phone number:<span class="asterx">*</span></label>
<div>
  <input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" required placeholder="Please enter your Phone number" pattern="[0-9]{9}" />
  <div class="error" id="e_tel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read your console.log errors and start from there, Also what `valueMissingeven`  should  even be? Obviously not functions or object parameters...

Comment: there are no errors in the console log. [valueMissing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) is the last one before Specifications section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have an error in console and it says:

```
TypeError: can't access property \"querySelector\", input.closest(...) is null",
```

So remove one div from:

```
closest("div div")
```

But your main problem is your `else` in both `validity` checks where you every time remove first message with second :

```
e_space.textContent = "";
```

Instead remove those `else` statements and make  a new `if`:

```
if (input.validity.valueMissing === false && input.validity.patternMismatch === false) {
      e_space.textContent = "";
      input.classList.remove("b-r");
    }
```

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs.forEach(function(input) {

  const e_space = input.closest("div").querySelector(".error");

  input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
    if (input.classList.contains("input-red")) {
      input.classList.remove("input-red")
    }
  })
  input.addEventListener("blur", function() {

    //pattern mismatch -still need to seperate them to text/number/email
    if (input.validity.patternMismatch) {
      if (e_space) {
        e_space.textContent = "This field can only contain letters from a-z.";
        input.classList.add("b-r");
      }
      input.classList.add("input-red");
    }


    //if empty
    input.value = input.value.trim();
    if (input.validity.valueMissing) {
      if (e_space) {
        e_space.textContent = "This field must not be empty.";
        input.classList.add("b-r");
      }
      input.classList.add("input-red");
    }

    if (input.validity.valueMissing === false && input.validity.patternMismatch === false) {
      e_space.textContent = "";
      input.classList.remove("b-r");
    }

  })
})
```

```html
<label for="surname">Surname:<span class="asterx">*</span></label>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" required placeholder="Please enter your Surname" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,15}" />
  <div class="error" id="e_surname"></div>
</div>
<label for="tel">Phone number:<span class="asterx">*</span></label>
<div>
  <input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" required placeholder="Please enter your Phone number" pattern="[0-9]{9}" />
  <div class="error" id="e_tel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Fixed the `closest` issue on js fiddle. I'll check again but I'm sure there is no error on my console log. give me a minute. Checked, no error in my console log.

Comment: Thank you. I think this should work. Will give it a try.

Comment: @WeAreDoomed I am talking about to SO snippet, not fiddle. I didint go to fiddle page, thats what snippets here are for ;). I sometime call them fiddle to. NP